# Angular 6: How to access an element from another component

Tags: angular

#### In `footer.component`

```
signIn() {
    const el = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.UserTrigger');
    console.log(el); // null
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
}
```

--

```
<a (click)="signIn()">Sign In</a>
```

---

#### In `header.component.html`

```
<div #userTrigger class="UserTrigger" (click)="loginModal()">Sign In</div>
```

### Question

In the above I am trying to click the login button in the footer which will trigger the signin modal which lives in the header. I know i can just reference the the modal in the footer but thats not what i want.

How do I access elements from another component?

Comment: Have you read the docs regarding component interaction here? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction just to know if you have already considered any of the methods described there or if those don't fit your use case

Comment: This is considered an anti-pattern. It would be better to bubble up an event from the footer to the parent notifying that a sign in event has been triggered and for this parent to interact with the header component to call the `loginModal()` public method on that component.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered migrating your login-related events/state into a dedicated service? You can then inject the service into any component which needs to respond to a (click) event and route this into the component in which your modal resides. This decouples the fact that two components which do not share a parent/child relationship need to interact in this way.